# Регулярное выражение: латиница, кирилица, пробел, дефис

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Регулярное выражением должно пропускать только латиницу, кирилицу пробелы и дефисы.

То есть, должен пропускать: Данте, Dante, Dante lol, Данте-LOL.

Но почему-то моя регулярка, описанная ниже, не работает как надо:

Тестирую так:

```
if (preg_match('/^[а-яА-Яa-zA-ZЁёәіңғүұқөһӘІҢҒҮҰҚӨҺ\-\s]*$/','Данте')) {
echo 1;
} else {
echo 2;
}
```

И по факту, в примере только валидная кирилица но почему то выдает всё равно "2" как невалидный результат.

Подскажите, пожалуйста. где я ошибся?

Comment: ``/^[а-яА-Яa-zA-ZЁёәіңғүұқөһӘІҢҒҮҰҚӨҺ\s-]*$/``?

Comment: Добавьте ключи `/um` для поддержки unicode и multiline. `'/^...$/um',$str`. Так же есть ключ `i` - для игнорирования регистра, можно убрать дублирующиеся диапазоны

Comment: `~^[\p{Cyrillic}\p{Latin} -]*$~i` как вариант, у тебя не хватает ключа `u` для работы с юникодом

Comment: @ipatev_nn спасибо помогло если конвертируете в ответ - помечу правильным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```regex
if (preg_match('/^[а-яА-Яa-zA-ZЁёәіңғүұқөһӘІҢҒҮҰҚӨҺ\-\s]*$/','Данте')) {
...
```

Само по себе регулярное выражение составлено верно, но не указаны необходимые флаги:
`u` - поддержка unicode, для работы с кириллицей
`m` - поддержка multiline, для возможности установить начало`^` и конец`$` строки.
`i` - игнорирование регистра символов
Дополнительно:
Я бы изменил `\s` только на горизонтальные пробельные символы `\h` и что бы не экранировать дефис`-` установил бы его в начале или конце шаблона, а так же установил бы квантификатор запрещающий 0 символов, к примеру `+` или `{1,}` означающие один и более символов, иначе `true` вернет пустая строка.

```regex
if (preg_match('/^[А-ЯA-ZёәіңғүұқөһӘІҢҒҮҰҚӨҺ\h-]+$/umi','Данте')) {
...
```

---

Даже с учетом изменения квантификатора, есть риск того, что успешно пройдет валидацию строка состоящая из пробелов и табуляций.